# Как сохранять данные в базе данных SQL на определенное время?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

**Как сделать так, чтобы некоторые данные в таблице удалялись по истечении определенного промежутка времени?**

Используются ли для этого только база данных? Или же сторонний софт и/или отдельно написанный код?

В общем, подскажите, пожалуйста, и прикрепите пример, если не сложно.

Comment: Используется планировщик, который периодически запускает процесс чистки - удаления записей с протухшим сроком годности. Некоторые СУБД имеют встроенный планировщик, некоторые нет, и тогда используется внешний.

Comment: почему в хештеге указана sqlite?

Comment: @strawdog, наверное, автор ее использует :)

Answer (score 1):

На базе данных нужно:

- добавить столбец с датой когда значение будет не актуально,
- добавить view, в котором будут выбираться только актуальные записи,
- добавить триггер на insert, который удалит не актульные записи.

Для каких-то данных в памяти питона можно использовать модуль cachetools и [TTLCache](https://cachetools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#cachetools.TTLCache) класс.

Для больших проектов такие вещи хранят в [redis](https://redis.io/commands/expireat) или memcached.